# php condition code show a different result than expected

Tags: php

This code should print the result in a green color if the condition are true and but instead it is print a blue color [like in the 'else' code]

```
<?php
$col = null;

$chek = 51200;
$chek -= 5200;

if ($chek / 1000 == 0 && (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000) {
    $col = "style='color:green;'";
    $save .= "$co . $a1 * $b1 = $span $col> $l </span> </br> </br>";
} else {
    $col = "style='color:blue;'";
}
$res = "<span $col> $chek </span>";

echo $res;
```

Comment: Please share your full code

Comment: What conditions you exactly want to check.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this `if($chek / 1000 == 0`

Because 46000 / 1000 != 0

I think you want to put != rather than ==

I hope i helped you :)

Comment: ((51200- 5200 )% 10000)

Answer (score 0):

`$chek / 1000` = 46, not 0; therefore the if statement fails.

The code works if you change

`if ($chek / 1000 == 0 && (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000) {`
to
`if ($chek / 1000 == 0 || (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000) {`

Answer (score 0):

change your code:

```
if ($chek / 1000 == 0 && (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000)
```

to:

```
if (($chek / 1000 == 0) || (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000)
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($chek / 1000 == 0 && (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000) {
```

to

```
if ($chek / 1000 != 0 && (($chek % 10000) * 2) == 12000) {
```

Comment: requires an explanation!